# pandas one-hot-encoding column containing a list of feature and each feature can be negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

So i have the following dataset

```
d = {'user': ['a','a','b','b'], 'item':[1, 2, 1, 3], 'features': [[2], [-2, -1], [-137, -1, 2], [-137, 2, 1]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

        user       item     features
0     a            1        [2]
1     a            2        [-2, -1]
2     b            1        [-137, -1, 2]
3     b            3        [-137, 2, 1]
```

i'm trying to obtain the following dataset:

```
        user       item     '2'    '1'    '137'
0     a            1        1      0      0
1     a            2        -1     -1     0
2     b            1        1      -1     -1
3     b            3        1      1      -1
```

i tried to use:

```
dataset = load_dataset()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
dataset = dataset.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(dataset.pop('features')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=dataset.index))
```

but i obtained this:

```
        user       item     '-1' '-137'  '-2' '1' '2'
0     a            1        0    0       0    0   1
1     a            2        1    0       1    0   0
2     b            1        1    1       0    0   1
3     b            3        0    1       0    1   1
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: can you share the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Can you explain your logic? In particular, why is `1` having a value of `-1` in row 0? Shouldn't it be 0 following your pattern?

Comment: @user2246849 yes i corrected

Comment: @onyambu on which df ? the first ones ?

Comment: Of course it was for the first one. I hope the features are in a list and not a string. Thats what the solution I posted reflects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas this can be done as follows:

```
df1 = df.explode('features')
df1['f1'] = abs(df1.features)
df1['f2'] = np.sign(df1.features)
df1.pivot(['user', 'item'], 'f1', 'f2').fillna(0).reset_index()

f2 user  item  1  2  137
0     a     1  0  1    0
1     a     2 -1 -1    0
2     b     1 -1  1   -1
3     b     3  1  1   -1
```

Comment: it doesn not work i obtaiin something different , i will post these result in a separate answer @onyambu

Comment: @Salsa94 what do you mean by itdoes not work? You get an error? Wrong results? I ran the code with the data you provided and it produces what I have provided above which is exactly similar to what you want